# Traverse string and replace symbols with their RTF escape representation in Java

Tags: java, string, character-encoding, rtf

I am attempting to process several large text files and to replace their symbols such as #,@,$,= etc. with their corresponding RTF escape representation.

List of rtf char representations :
https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/rtf-pocket-guide/9781449302047/ch04.html

The temporary solution that I have implemented is to store some of those characters into an array and in case of match to replace them. The problem is that the files that I process are subject of change and it is typical for them to evolve. In some cases they have new symbols that are not present into my rtf array and updating the array is not an option. I can assume that adding all of the symbols from the list into the array is probably a very inefficient solution.

Could you please suggest me better and efficient solution to the problem or some concrete library ?

Comment: The link gives the answer: RTF escapes (\'xx) are valid for all characters, the only characters that have to be escaped are these three characters: {, }, and \, plus all the characters over code 127. So search for those three plus all with numeric codes > 127 and replace them. No need for an array as the mapping from numeric code to escape is trivial (hex code).

Comment: I don't think this helps. @ewramner